# How to capture and display filename

Tags: ansible

I used below Ansible playbook to capture the filename, but I'm facing error

```
task:
  - copy:
      src: /tmp/example.tar.gz
      dest: /opt/
    register: filename

  - debug: var=filename
```

I need to capture the filename and to be displayed on the console.

Answer (score 1):

According your example of [copy files to remote locations](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html) the filename seems to be already known.

If you like to [set host variable(s) and fact(s)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_fact_module.html) you could use a construct of

```yaml
- name: Set fact
  set_fact:
    FILENAME: "example.tar.gz"

- name: Show fact
  debug:
    msg: "{{ FILENAME }}"

- name: Copy file {{ FILENAME }}
  copy:
    src: /tmp/{{ FILENAME }}
    dest: /opt
```

If you are interested in [registering](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#registering-variables) the [return values](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/common_return_values.html) of the [copy module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#return-values) you could use

```yaml
- name: Copy file
  copy:
    src: /tmp/example.tar.gz
    dest: /opt
  register: result

- name: Show copied file
  debug:
    msg: "{{ result.dest }}"
```